# What does "select((select(s),$|=1)[0])" do in Perl?

Tags: perl, select, buffering

I've seen some horrific code written in Perl, but I can't make head nor tail of this one:

```
select((select(s),$|=1)[0])
```

It's in some networking code that we use to communicate with a server and I assume it's something to do with buffering (since it sets `$|`).

But I can't figure out why there's multiple `select` calls or the array reference. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: please check [perldoc -f select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html). For the meaning of `$|`, please check [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: To confuse and frustrate people who have to maintain the code, i.e. you.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's a nasty little idiom for setting autoflush on a filehandle other than STDOUT.

`select()` takes the supplied filehandle and (basically) replaces STDOUT with it, and it returns the old filehandle when it's done.

So `(select($s),$|=1)` redirects the filehandle (remember `select` returns the old one), and sets autoflush (`$| = 1`). It does this in a list (`(...)[0]`) and returns the first value (which is the result of the `select` call - the original STDOUT), and then passes *that* back into another `select` to reinstate the original STDOUT filehandle. Phew.

But now you understand it (well, maybe ;)), do this instead:

```
use IO::Handle;
$fh->autoflush;
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant nasty as in dodgy-functionality rather than lack-of-clarity.  So it's passing the result of the inner select to the outer select, reselecting the original. That makes sense now but you're right, I'll probably scrap it and use autoflush.

Comment: I wrote that ugly piece of code long before IO::Handle->autoflush existed.  Please let it die a quiet death. :)

Comment: @Randal: So *you're* to blame! My apologies for describing it as 'nasty', in the context of IO::Handle->autoflush not existing then it is indeed a crafty little chunk of code ;) (/me backpedals furiously)

Comment: I don’t see any reason to use the Lisp-ish version. Even in absence of IO::Handle you can write it much more nicely by using `for` to topicalise the old handle for re-selection. See my answer.

Comment: `perl -wE 'open OUTPUT, ">", undef; say select(OUTPUT)'` doesn't print out main::STDOUT. Why?

Comment: @DavidFarrell because the first argument to `say` is a filehandle ;-) Try `say STDOUT select(OUTPUT)`.

Answer (score 30):

The way to figure out any code is to pick it apart. You know that stuff inside parentheses happens before stuff outside. This is the same way you'd figuring out what code is doing in other languages.

The first bit is then:

```
( select(s), $|=1 )
```

That list has two elements, which are the results of two operations: one to select the `s` filehandle as the default then one to set `$|` to a true value. The `$|` is one of the per-filehandle variables which only apply to the currently selected filehandle (see [Understand global variables](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/09/understand-global-variables/) at *The Effective Perler*). In the end, you have a list of two items: the previous default filehandle (the result of `select`), and 1.

The next part is a literal list slice to pull out the item in index 0:

```
( PREVIOUS_DEFAULT, 1 )[0]
```

The result of that is the single item that is previous default filehandle.

The next part takes the result of the slice and uses it as the argument to another call to `select`

```
 select( PREVIOUS_DEFAULT );
```

So, in effect, you've set `$|` on a filehandle and ended up back where you started with the default filehandle.

Answer (score 21):

```
select($fh)
```

Select a new default file handle. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html

```
(select($fh), $|=1)
```

Turn on autoflush. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

```
(select($fh), $|=1)[0]
```

Return the first value of this tuple.

```
select((select($fh), $|=1)[0])
```

`select` it, i.e. restore the old default file handle.

---

Equivalent to

```
$oldfh = select($fh);
$| = 1;
select($oldfh);
```

which means

```
use IO::Handle;
$fh->autoflush(1);
```

as demonstrated in the perldoc page.

Comment: If someone doesn't want to use `IO::Handle` the least they could do is wrap this monstrosity in a function like `sub flush ($) { select((select($_[0]), $|=1)[0]); }`

Comment: If you're going to put it in a function then you might as well write it the long way with the temporary to hold the old handle. :)

Comment: @hobbs - Eh, I could go either way. For functions that simple, once it's in a function, you never really have to look at it again, nor is the functionality of a `flush` function ever likely to change. Perhaps the horrific version is slightly faster. Perhaps you can use it to scare an intern.

Answer (score 10):

In another venue, I once proposed that a more comprehensible version would be thus:

```
for ( select $fh ) { $| = 1; select $_ }
```

This preserves the compact idiom’s sole advantage that no variable needs be declared in the surrounding scope.

Or if you’re not comfortable with `$_`, you can write it like this:

```
for my $prevfh ( select $fh ) { $| = 1; select $prevfh }
```

The scope of `$prevfh` is limited to the `for` block. (But if you write Perl you really have no excuse to be skittish about `$_`.)

Comment: Both yours and Randall's versions are less than obvious, but at least Randall's has the advantage of being short.. Is there some reason why my $old_fh = select($fh); $| = 1; select($old_fh); doesn't work? As if it's comprehensibility you're going for it would seem a considerably more sensible choice

Comment: Did you see any claims about it not working? In any case if you actually want a sensible choice you’ll use IO::Handle. As for shortness, Randall’s has a 1–4 character advantage depending on whitespace.

Comment: That was a completely honest question, by the way. I've never been in a position where I've had to do it (at least where IO::Handle hasn't been available).

Comment: So go ahead and use it. I didn’t claim that my solution was the best nor that any other solution doesn’t work; I merely offered, in the spirit of TMTOWTDI, a Perl-ish rather than Lisp-ish idiom.

Comment: I like Aristotle's version better than Randall's because it doesn't rely on execution order in a list, which (having cut my teeth on Scheme) I am suspicious of.

Answer (score 7):

It's overly clever code for turning on buffer flushing on handle `s` and then re-selecting the current handle.

See `perldoc -f select` for more.

Answer (score 3):

It is overoptimization to skip loading IO::Handle.

```
use IO::Handle;
$fh->autoflush(1);
```

is much more readable.

Comment: I wouldn't say overoptimization.  using lexical filehandles is a *relatively* new thing

Comment: true.  I work with a codebase that has a number of scripts from back then.  Until recently I maintained things written in perl 4.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: it can be used with non-lexical filehandles too.