# What does “select((select(s),$|=1)[0])” do in Perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “select((select(s),$|=1)[0])” do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196754/what-does-selectselects-10-do-in-perl)

What's the purpose of the second line ?

```
open my $fh, '>>', $logfile or die $!;
select((select($fh), $|=1)[0]);
```