# Perl: Out of Memory

Tags: perl

I receive about 7000 objects from a database and write each item to a JSON file.
After about 2000 objects perl terminates with a `Out of memory` error. In the beginning all database objects are received and obviously they fit perfectly into memory. The error happends during the loop.

I'm quite new to perl and I don't know why this happens. From my point of view, there is no memory allocation in the loop that cannot be free-ed after each iteration.

Here is my code:

```
use lib '../AcePerl/blib/lib','../AcePerl/blib/arch';
use Ace;
use JSON;
use Data::Structure::Util qw( unbless );
use List::MoreUtils;
use strict vars;

use constant HOST => $ENV{ACEDB_HOST} || 'mining.wormbase.org';
use constant PORT => $ENV{ACEDB_PORT} || 2005;

$|=1;

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;

print "Opening the database....";
my $db = Ace->connect(-host=>HOST,-port=>PORT
              -cache => {
                         cache_root         => '/usr/tmp/acedb',
                         cache_depth        => 4,
                         default_expires_in => '1 week'
                         }
) || die "Connection failure: ",Ace->error;
print "done.\n";

#my @anatomies = $db->list('Anatomy_Term','WBbt:000547*');
my @anatomies = $db->fetch(-name    => '*',
                           -class   => 'Anatomy_Term',
                           -fill    => true,
#                           -count   => 10
                          );

#my @anatomies = $db->list('Anatomy_Term','*');

print scalar(@anatomies), " anatomy terms found!\n";

my $i = 0;
my $c;

sub wbstr {
  my $arg = $_[0];
  if(!defined $arg) {
    return undef;
  }else{
    return $arg->name;}
}

# parse anatomy terms for cells
my %anatomy_data;

open (MYFILE, '>anatomy-data2.txt');
print MYFILE '{';

my $parent;
my $first;
my $ancestor;
my $expr_ancestor;
my $is_a;

foreach $c (@anatomies) {
  if($i!=0) {
    print MYFILE ',';
  }

  $i++;
  print MYFILE $json->encode(wbstr($c)), ':{';

  print MYFILE '"term":', $json->encode(wbstr($c->Term)), ',';
  print MYFILE '"definition":', $json->encode(wbstr($c->Definition)), ',';
  print MYFILE '"synonym":', $json->encode(wbstr($c->Synonym)), ',';

  print MYFILE '"parents":[';
  $first = true;
  foreach $parent ($c->CELL_p) {
    if($first eq false) {
      print MYFILE ',';
    }
    print MYFILE $json->encode(wbstr($parent));
    $first = false;
  }
  print MYFILE '],';

  print MYFILE '"ancestors":[';
  $first = true;
  foreach $ancestor ($c->Ancestor) {
    if($first eq false) {
      print MYFILE ',';
    }
    print MYFILE $json->encode(wbstr($ancestor));
    $first = false;
  }
  print MYFILE '],';


  print MYFILE '"expr_ancestors":[';
  $first = true;
  foreach $expr_ancestor ($c->Expr_ancestor) {
    if($first eq false) {
      print MYFILE ',';
    }
    print MYFILE $json->encode(wbstr($expr_ancestor));
    $first = false;
  }
  print MYFILE '],';

  print MYFILE '"is_a":[';
  $first = true;
  foreach $is_a ($c->IS_A_p) {
    if($first eq false) { 
      print MYFILE ',';
    }
    print MYFILE $json->encode(wbstr($is_a));
    $first = false;
  }
  print MYFILE ']}';
}
print MYFILE '}';

print "Done\n";

close (MYFILE);
```

Comment: N.B. `true` and `false` are not reserved words in Perl.

Comment: You should be running with `use warnings; use strict;`.  There could be many many bugs you're hiding.  As it is, the places where you're saying `$first = true` should be throwing a warning because that is an archaic equivalent for `$first = "true"`.  Add the warnings/strict and see what comes out.  It probably won't fix your memory problems but it will turn up bad things you're doing.

Comment: Ok, I better use fetch_many() instead of fetch(). Then I don't run into memory trouble. ;)

Comment: I wonder if the behavior would change if you `shift` entries out of `@anatomies` after processing them?

Comment: @user2004469 So is this solved by using fetch_many()? Then please answer yourself.

Answer (score -1):

try to flush your file (or insert a "\n" at some point in your print MYFILE statements). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538767/how-flush-file-in-perl) may helps you