# Re-redirecting output to stdout from within Perl script

Tags: perl, debugging

Say I am debugging a Perl script where the script was invoked as follows:

```
perl -d  test.pl > file.txt
```

with  `test.pl`:

```
print "Hello world\n";
my $a = 2;
print "$a\n";
1;
```

Is there any way to **re-redirect** the output of the script from within the debugger to the **debugger stdout** so that the print statements send their output on the scroll window of the debugger?

If not, is there any way to issue a command from within the debugger to **flush out** everything so far to `file.txt`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538767/how-flush-file-in-perl for how to flush output in perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate arbitrary Perl while debugging, and DB::OUT is the filehandle opened by the debugger for output.  So just use `select DB::OUT`:

Given test:

```
use v5.14;
say 1;
say 2;
say 3;
```

Here's a log demonstrating the use of select:

```
$ perl -d test > log

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(test:2):     say 1;
  DB<1> n
main::(test:3):     say 2;
  DB<1> select DB::OUT

  DB<2> n
2
main::(test:4):     say 3;
  DB<2> n
3
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<2> q
$ cat log
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Julian Fondren works, there is a minor change necessary to work remote.

given test:

```
use v5.14;
say 1;
say 2;
say 3;
```

Start a listener on whatever host and port on terminal 1 (here localhost:12345):

```
$ nc -v -l localhost -p 12345
```

for readline support use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/#rlwrap) (you can use on `perl -d` too):

```
$ rlwrap nc -v -l localhost -p 12345
```

And start the test on another terminal (say terminal 2):

```
$ PERLDB_OPTS="RemotePort=localhost:12345" perl -d test
```

Input/Output on terminal 1:

```
Connection from 127.0.0.1:42994

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.49
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(test:2): say 1;
  DB<1> n
main::(test:3): say 2;
  DB<1> select $DB::OUT

  DB<2> n
2
main::(test:4): say 3;
  DB<2> n
3
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.  
  DB<2>
```

Output on terminal 2:

```
1
```

Note the dollar on

```
select $DB::OUT
```

NOTE: I don't mind if someone explain what magic is behind that change, but don't ask me because I don't know.