# What does "[0]" mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

What is the [0] doing in this code:

```
select((select(LOG_FILE),$!=1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I answered this ten years ago! [What does “select((select(s),$|=1)[0])” do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196754/what-does-selectselects-10-do-in-perl)

---

You're looking at a single element access to a list. The expression in side the parentheses produces some sort of list and  the `[0]` selects one item from the list.

This bit of code is a very old idiom to set a per-filehandle kinda-global variable. I think you probably meant `$|` (the autoflush setting) instead of `$!`.

First, remember that Perl has the concept of a "default filehandle". That starts out as standard output, but you can change it. That's what the `select` does.

Next, realize that each file handle knows its own settings for various things; these are represented by special variables such as `$|` (see [perlvar's section on "Variables related to Filehandles"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)). When you change these variables, they apply to the current default filehandle.

So, what you see in this idiom is an inner `select` that changes the default filehandle. You change the default then set `$|` to whatever value you want. It looks a bit odd because you have two expressions separated by a comma instead of a semicolon, the use statement separator:

```
(select(LOG_FILE), $|=1)
```

From this, the idiom wants the result of the `select`; that's the previous default filehandle. To get that you want the first item in that list. That's in index 0:

```
(select(LOG_FILE), $|=1)[0]
```

The result of that entire expression is the previous default filehandle, which you now want to restore. Do that with the outer `select`:

```
select((select(LOG_FILE), $|=1)[0]);
```

You could have written that with an intermediate variable:

```
my $previous = select LOG_FILE;
$| = 1;
select($previous);
```

If you're writing new stuff on your own, you might use scalar variable for the filehandle then call its `autoflush` method:

```
open my $log_file_fh, '>', $log_filename or die ...;
$log_file_fh->autoflush(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`( LIST1 )[ LIST2 ]` is a list slice. In list context, it evaluates to the elements of `LIST1` specified by `LIST2`.

In this case, it returns the result of the `select`.

---

```
select((select(LOG_FILE),$!=1)[0]);
```

should be

```
select((select(LOG_FILE),$|=1)[0]);
```

The latter enables auto-flushing for the `LOG_FILE` file handle. It can be written more clearly as follows:

```
use IO::Handle ();       # Only needed in older versions of Perl.
LOG_FILE->autoflush(1);
```

---

By the way, you shouldn't be using global variables like that. Instead of

```
open LOG_FILE, ...
```

you should be using

```
open my $LOG_FILE, ...
```

Comment: So the OP meant to write `$|` instead of `$!` ?

Comment: @clamp, Yeah. Fixed